# Responsive code is not working in mobile with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js on my page and it's working. I am getting on issues on a mobile device. I mean I added some responsive code for mobile devices but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //initialising fullpage.js in the jQuery way
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#ff5f45', '#0798ec', '#fc6c7c', '#fec401'],
    navigation: true,
    slidesNavigation: true,
  });
});
```

```css
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .a-herosliderContent h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  .a-herosliderContent p {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/fullpage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section slide01 banner-bg">
    <div class="a-heroslider">
      <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
        <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="aboutus">About Us <span><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section slide02 banner-bg">
    <div class="a-heroslider">
      <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
        <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="product-category">View Products <span><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section slide03 banner-bg">
    <div class="a-heroslider">
      <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
        <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="service">View Services <span><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/fullpage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove this lines

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/fullpage.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/fullpage.js"></script>
```

and I added these lines to your code:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- fullPage CSS and JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.min.css" />
<script type="text/JavaScript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
```

I hope I've been helpful

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
            .a-herosliderContent h2 {
                font-size: 80px;
            }

            .a-herosliderContent p {
                font-size: 40px;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <!-- fullPage CSS and JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.min.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section slide01 banner-bg">
            <div class="a-heroslider">
                <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>
                    <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="aboutus">About Us <span><i
                                    class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section slide02 banner-bg">
            <div class="a-heroslider">
                <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>
                    <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="product-category">View Products <span><i
                                    class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section slide03 banner-bg">
            <div class="a-heroslider">
                <div class="a-herosliderContent centerFromTop">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>
                    <div class="a-heroCTA a-allCTA"><a href="service">View Services <span><i
                                    class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //initialising fullpage.js in the jQuery way
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#ff5f45', '#0798ec', '#fc6c7c', '#fec401'],
                navigation: true,
                slidesNavigation: true,
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you add the jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js and jquery.fullPage.min.js at the top? the script always comes at the bottom. right?

Comment: Please check my screenshot of the view source https://prnt.sc/vp5pmx https://prnt.sc/vp5pwu

Comment: If I understand correctly, you copies the code from my example, but it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code. Can you check it once again where is the issue with my code?

Comment: From the screenshot I saw the problem! Move "$ (document) .ready (function () {...." to the bottom of the page

Comment: In the "Code snippet" example in SO the system arranges the code in this way but when you copy it you have to put the JS code at the bottom in the page.

Comment: Yes I added at the bottom but still not working for me.

Comment: You can check the screenshot here https://prnt.sc/vp5zv5

Comment: I made an update ... copy the whole page from my example

Comment: I have doubts why you added a script link and CSS link inside the body? Is this the correct way to use it?

Comment: No, this is not the right way but for me it is faster to test the code. Now everything is where it should be and it still works in the example

Comment: This is definetely not a solution :)
You in fact moved away from the latest fullPage.js version 3 to version 2.6.6 that is quite old, not maintained nor supported and for which you won't find extensions or wrappers.

Comment: I am glad that you, as the creator of "fullpage.js", joined the comments. I hope you give the correct answer to the OP

Comment: @Alvaro, Do you know the correct way to solve this issue? Please help me in this

Comment: There's no way fullPage.js will prevent media queries from working. So definitely there's something wrong that is not fullPage.js related :) 
Check the css styles you are importing, remove them one by one until your responsive media queries work again, then you will find the file that is interfering with it.

Comment: @Alvaro, No I haven't added my CSS. I just added the bootstrap plugin and the rest of the plugins are from fullpage.js. I added only the media query which I already added in the question.